# How to catch an error thrown in XMLHttpRequest's onload method

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am `throw`ing an exception from the `onload` method of my `XMLHttpRequest` object. However I am unable to `catch` that error using a `try` `catch` block.

I have the following code in my `_fetch(url, callback)` function:

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

xhr.onload = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
    // if (xhr.status === 200) callback(xhr.response)

    // throw a 'custom' error if the server responds with 501
    if (xhr.status === 501) throw new Error('Answer not found') /
  }
}

// rest of the fn
```

Then, I am using the `_fetch` function:

```js
try {
  _fetch(endPoint, response => console.log(response))
} catch (error) { // error not caught
  console.log(error)
}
```

However, the error is not caught and instead an error is thrown — `Uncaught Error: Answer not found`

#### What I have tried:

- `try` `catching`ing the `send()` method of the `xhr` object in `_fetch`
- `try` `catching`ing the `open()` method of the `xhr` object in `_fetch`
- using the `onerror` method of the `xhr` object — won't work because the request is completed successfully

**So, how can I `catch` that error?**

To try out the full code, check out [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nevilleomangi/9utmo7ph/15/) fiddle.

---

#### Why do you need to `throw` the error in the `onload` method?

I am getting data from a certain API, and due to some restriction, I can't use `fetch`. I am using `XMLHttpRequest` instead. The server responds with the error code `501 - Not Implemented` if the query I have sent cannot be *answered*.
Thus I need to pick out that error code, and carry out some functionality.

Obviously, there are other possible ways to achieve my end goal, but I'm finding it hard to wrap my head around why this won't work. I have read up on both `throw` and `XMLHttprequest` but I may have a misunderstanding of how one of them works.

Answer (score 5):

You absolutely can use fetch to make this not only easier on yourself, but to work with the errors.  JSFiddle link below this code.

```
const url = `http://api.wolframalpha.com/v1/result?appid=H2R834-AUAJXG9KRV&i=%3F`
fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/${url}`)
.then(res => {
    console.log(res.status)
    if (res.status == 200) {
        return res.json()
    }
    else if (res.status == 501) {
        throw new Error("Answer not found")
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Some other status code")
    }
})
.then(json => { 
    console.log(json) 
})
.catch(err => { 
    console.error(err)
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mparson8/ug1hoks8/9/

Comment: Hey, thanks, this works. There must have been some oversight on my part (certainly while trying to bypass the CORS restriction).

Still, I can't understand why I can't catch the error from the onload method. It would be great to understand that. In the meantime, I'll switch over to fetch.

Comment: Fetch is powerful, flexible, easy to use, and you can polyfill it if you're worried about browser compatibility. With that being said, my theory is that since you're throwing the error within a function that is within another function, the error is not being hoisted into the outer `_fetch` function so the `try..catch` block can't do anything with it.  I was able to successfully catch the error in your `try...catch` block by sending the error back through the callback [like in this JSFiddle with your code](https://jsfiddle.net/mparson8/wnzjmrgs/1/)

Answer (score -1):

While you can use a library to make your life easier,

`XMLHttpRequest` onXXXX are actually event handlers, onload being only one of many possible events. The full list is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Events

In this case, you have a missing error handler:

`xhr.onerror( ... )`

Also, if you have access to a modern browser, please use 
`xhr.addEventListener('load'|'error'|..., ... )` instead. This actually allows multiple handlers, removing handlers, etc.

---

Regarding your sample code:

`function _fetch(url, callback)`

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

xhr.onload = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
    // if (xhr.status === 200) callback(xhr.response)

    // throw a 'custom' error if the server responds with 501
    if (xhr.status === 501) throw new Error('Answer not found')
    // This can never be caught because async functions break the stack.
    // Intuition: If you can't return it, you can't throw either.
  }
}

// rest of the fn
```

Then, I am using the _fetch function:

```
try {
  _fetch(endPoint, response => console.log(response))
} catch (error) { // error not caught
  console.log(error)
}
```

In this case, you need to modify the fetch's callback to use two parameters, in a [similar style to node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/errors/what-are-the-error-conventions/)

In particular: `_fetch(endPoint, (err, resp) => ... )`

```
xhr.onload = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
    // if (xhr.status === 200) callback(null, xhr.response)

    // throw a 'custom' error if the server responds with 501
    if (xhr.status === 501) callback(new Error('Answer not found'), null);
  }
}
```

Of course, the smart way is to use promises (or a library). Ensure you call either resolve or reject, at least once.

```
function _fetch(endpoint, callback) {
   return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
        // if (xhr.status === 200) resolve(xhr.response)

        // throw a 'custom' error if the server responds with 501
        if (xhr.status === 501) reject(new Error('Answer not found'));
        }
      }

   });
}
```

This allows you to use it as follows:

```
_fetch(endpoint)
.then ( res => console.log('result', res) )
.catch( e => console.log('error', e);
```

Comment: `fetch` doesn't require an external library to use. It's built in to ECMAScript 6 and all modern browsers because of this. And it's just much easier to use (and more powerful) than `XMLHttpRequest`.  I'd recommend familiarizing yourself with `fetch` because you'll never want to use `XMLHttpRequest` again!

Comment: @MarcusParsons Agreed, it did slip my mind. Then again, its still considered experimental. 

I actually recommend libraries over experimental browser features. That way they work consistently across browsers/node.js and tend to be more convenient overall (e.g. automatically stringifying JSON).

Comment: The MDN has a polyfill for support with older browsers so that you can maintain the ease of use of `fetch`. The polyfill is basically just syntactic sugar for `XMLHttpRequest`.  But, I feel like I'm talking to my dog now since I've said `fetch` so many times haha

Comment: Hey @blackening. Thanks for the tip, event listeners for the win! 

As I had clarified, using the onerror method of the xhr object won't work because the request is completed successfully (onerror is commented out in the fiddle). No error will be triggered in xhr in the case of a server 501 error.

Comment: Oh that, the "catch" literally? I'll update the answer later. Basically you need to callback properly. You can't throw inside a callback and expect to catch it. Either you return callback the error node style, or you create a promise and reject it.